# BibTeX to endnote bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, conversion, endnotes

I was working with a software called KNIME and I needed to cite this software for, the citation provided by the website is in the BibTeX format.

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{BCDG+07,
author = {Michael R. Berthold and Nicolas Cebron and Fabian Dill and Thomas R. Gabriel and
Tobias K\"{o}tter and Thorsten Meinl and Peter Ohl and Christoph Sieb and Kilian Thiel and
Bernd Wiswedel},
title = {{KNIME}: The {K}onstanz {I}nformation {M}iner},
booktitle = {Studies in Classification, Data Analysis, and Knowledge Organization (GfKL 2007)},
publisher = {Springer},
ISBN = {978-3-540-78239-1},
ISSN = {1431-8814},
year = {2007}
}
```

I am not a BibTeX or even a LaTeX user. But I would like to convert this citation into the endnote format. I tried to find a way to do that online but failed. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type `convert bibtex to endnote` into Google, the first search result is [this Java program](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~tapted/bib2endnote.html). There is also [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net), although this is a full-featured bibliography manager.

Comment: Hi ChrisS, I have downloaded the program, pasted my biblography into the textbox, and saved it via "Save endnote XML". The saved file was of 0 bytes size and did not import into the endnote, although i used the "Import > Endnote generated XML". Any idea what went wrong here? Sorry if this sounds very technical, but it is my first time using the Java and LaTeX environment! Cheers.

Comment: @Error404 I don't know what went wrong; I tried it on my own computer and it worked. I've uploaded the result to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pSkgVQeA) for you.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

I put this BibTeX entry into JabRef.

`File->export marked entry` - In the save interface choose `format: Endnote (*.txt)` and save the file. (naming can be slightly wrong. I translated to English from my German JabRef...)

The result:

```
%0 
%0 Conference Proceedings
%A Berthold, Michael R.; Cebron, Nicolas; Dill, Fabian; Gabriel, Thomas R.; K\"o,tter, Tobias; Meinl, Thorsten; Ohl, Peter; Sieb, Christoph; Thiel, Kilian & Wiswedel, Bernd
%D 2007
%T KNIME: The Konstanz Information Miner
%E 
%B Studies in Classification, Data Analysis, and Knowledge Organization (GfKL 2007)
%C 
%I Springer
%V 
%6
%N 
%P 
%& 
%Y 
%S 
%7
%8 
%9
%? 
%! 
%Z 
%@ 978-3-540-78239-1
%(
%)
%*
%L
%M


%2 
%3 inproceedings
%4 
%# 
%$ 
%F BCDG+07
%K 
%X 
%Z 


%+
%^
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the path of your bibtex file is `D:\abc.bib` and the path of JabRef is `D:\JabRef-3.0.jar`, you can generate endnote file `D:\abc.enw` using the following command on windows:

```
D:\JabRef-3.0.jar -o D:\abc.enw,endnote -n true D:\abc.bib
```

Click [here](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/CommandLine.php) for the reference of the command line options.

You can also create a windows batch script (.bat) for conversion when a `.bib` file is open by the following steps.

1. Create batch script `bib2enw.bat` containing

   `D:\JabRef-3.0.jar -o D:\abc.enw,endnote -n true %1`

   `D:\abc.enw`
2. Associate `.bat` files with the batch script `bib2enw.bat`