# Conversion of BibTeX to Endnote bibliography [02/12/2015]

Tags: bibtex, conversion, endnotes

After searching online on converting *BibTex* bibliography files to *Endnote X7*, I found a few useful links, such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129735) and [that](http://www.lib.uts.edu.au/question/5955/how-can-i-import-bibliography-endnote-bibtex-latex-what-about-converting-other-way). However, it seems these links are outdated and the suggested software are no longer available, especially [JabRef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JabRef) which seems to be a sophisticated program and also [a Java program](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~tapted/bib2endnote.html) which the provided link does not work.

Could someone share with the community if there is any update on this conversion (BibTex to Endnote)? Is there any new tool? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say this question is a dupe of the older one: just 'it was a while ago' doesn't mean the question is new (a bounty on the old one would be one way to attract new answers). At the same time, I'm not sure what we can say further on this: JabRef can export RIS format for reading by EndNote, while EndNote's own capabilities are definitely off-topic for us.

Comment: JabRef isn't unavailable ... http://jabref.sourceforge.net/

Comment: BTW, I tested with JabRef exporting as both 'EndNote (`*.txt`)' and 'RIS (`*.ris`)' forms and these imported into EndNote X6 correctly as far as I checked. So there should be no major issue with the existing answer on the linked question.

Comment: Thank you all. JabRef is now accessible and probably their website was down at the time I visited it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As already noted in the comments: [`JabRef`](http://jabref.sourceforge.net) is alive and well and can do the task. But you also asked if there is another tool that can do the job. So here is my answer using [`bibutils`](http://sourceforge.net/p/bibutils/home/Bibutils/):

`bibutils` is a collection of programs that can convert to and from `MODS XML` as an intermediate format.

In order to convert from BibTeX to tagged Endnote simply call:

```
$ bib2xml input.bib | xml2end > output.enw
```

Converting to RIS is similar:

```
$ bib2xml input.bib | xml2ris > output.ris
```

Comment: JabRef crashes for me on Mojave :(. Seems like Mac port is broken since already in GitHub as a known bug.

Answer (score 1):

I do it with [bib2ris command](http://refdb.sourceforge.net/manual-0.9.4/x7139.html) :

```
bib2ris < foo.bib > foo.ris
```

Answer (score 1):

you could convert your `input.bib` file to `ris` online using this website [bibtex-converter](https://asouqi.github.io/bibtex-converter/)